# Run in full screen with no start menu

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making Winforms Fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649877/making-winforms-fullscreen)

I am making a VB Form that i want to run in full screen, as in covering the start menu
and task bar. right now i am using

```
    Me.Size = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
    Me.WindowState = 2
    Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    Me.TopMost = True
    Me.FormBorderStyle = 0
```

but the start menu still shows. I am assuming this is because the window is just maximized and not really in "full screen"

is there any way i can cover the start menu in vb to make the program run in full screen?

Comment: The question is the same but the proposed solution in the question (which is close to working but doesn't) is different.  Of those, this is the first to propose setting Me.Location to 0,0 and to use SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There appear to be some side-effects going on here.  If you just reorder the lines, it should work fine.  In fact, setting the WindowState to maximized or enabling "always on top" do not appear to be explicitly required to achieve this effect.

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Me.Location = New Point(0, 0)
Me.Size = SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
'Me.WindowState = 2
'Me.TopMost = True
```